# In a matplotlib barplot, how can I make sure very small bars are rendered with an equal width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a bar plot in matplotlib with many, many very narrow bars. Here's some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.poisson(1, size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 1))
ax.bar(x, y, width=1, facecolor='red', edgecolor='white', linewidth=1)
ax.grid(color='white', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')

# some plot aesthetics
for spine in ['right', 'top', 'left']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
```

[image]

Notice that due to the finite pixel resolution, the bars vary noticeably in rendered width.

What is the best way to create this plot in matplotlib while ensuring that the rendered result has equal-width bars?

Comment: maybe increase the output resolution, or save to a vector format (`pdf`, `eps`, etc.)?

Comment: Increasing the output resolution doesn't always seem to help, but I do get equal-width bars if I set `dpi` in `savefig` to a multiple of the `ppi` (72 points/pixels (?) per inch) that matplotlib uses. This also gets rid of the blurry edges of the bars.